# How to add images taken from camera to a Listview? Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin

I would like to add images to a Listview in Xamarin Forms?(or other layout) after each image is taken by the camera, something similar to the image above. How would I approach this?
[image: Something like this photo]

I used https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin example for taking/picking photos, but unsure on how to add them to the Listview or other layout in Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to hack the crap out of this to make it work and look exactly how you want, but this does work.  Refactor to MVVM, add bindings where required and be sure to change any and all aspects that don't work for you.

I've tested on iOS but not Android.  Given it's Forms, the only thing you should need to do is what you've already done and that's initialise the Media plugin.

Given it's quite dynamic, all of the visual work has been done in the view (code behind).

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="PlaypenApp.ImageGridPage">

    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid x:Name="ImageGridContainer" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        </Grid>        
    </ScrollView>    
</ContentPage>
```

**C# (Code Behind)**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;

namespace PlaypenApp
{
    public partial class ImageGridPage : ContentPage
    {
        private const int MaxColumns = 3;

        private double _rowHeight = 0;
        private int _currentRow = 0;
        private int _currentColumn = 0;

        public ImageGridPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await InitialiseMediaPermissions());

            var addPhotoButton = new Button()
            {
                Text = "Add Photo",
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#F0F0F0"),
                BorderWidth = 1,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#F9F9F9"),
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
            };

            addPhotoButton.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => await AddPhoto();

            ImageGridContainer.Children.Add(addPhotoButton, 0, 0);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                // Wait for a small amount of time so the UI has a chance to update the relevant values
                // we need to complete the operation.
                await Task.Delay(10);

                // Set the row height to be the same as the column width so that the image 
                // is presented in a square grid.
                _rowHeight = addPhotoButton.Width;
                ImageGridContainer.RowDefinitions[0].Height = _rowHeight;

                await ImageGridContainer.FadeTo(1);
            });
        }

        async Task AddPhoto()
        {
            MediaFile file = null;

            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "You need to fix the problem of camera availability", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var imageSource = await DisplayActionSheet("Image Source", "Cancel", null, new string[] { "Camera", "Photo Gallery" });
            var photoName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";

            switch (imageSource)
            {
                case "Camera":
                    file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        Directory = "Sample",
                        Name = photoName
                    });

                    break;

                case "Photo Gallery":
                    file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (file == null)
                return;

            // We have the photo, now add it to the grid.
            _currentColumn++;

            if (_currentColumn > MaxColumns - 1)
            {
                _currentColumn = 0;
                _currentRow++;

                // Add a new row definition by copying the first row.
                ImageGridContainer.RowDefinitions.Add(ImageGridContainer.RowDefinitions[0]);
            }

            var newImage = new Image()
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                Scale = 0
            };

            ImageGridContainer.Children.Add(newImage, _currentColumn, _currentRow);

            await Task.Delay(250);

            await newImage.ScaleTo(1, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
        }

        async Task InitialiseMediaPermissions()
        {
            var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
            var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);

            if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted || storageStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Camera, Permission.Storage });
                cameraStatus = results[Permission.Camera];
                storageStatus = results[Permission.Storage];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... I'm essentially just adding rows dynamically to the grid as I need to.

I hope that helps you anyway.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: It works really well. Thank you for your help. Code is really easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xamarin Forms 3.0 this can be implemented using Flexlayout

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just a quick snapshot of what Brad code look like.

```cs
//if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
//{
//    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "You need to fix the problem of camera availability", "OK");
//    return;
//}

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
{
    DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
    return;
}
```

Change the validation check to IsPickPhotoSupported if anyone is running it on the Emulator as Camera control does not work on Emulator ( or is it just me?).